# is it possible to pass data from one python program to another python program?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, parallel-processing

Both programs are running in parallel. i want to send a list of numpy images as list acquired from program 1 to program 2 which then process the imageson it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show us your current implementation?

Comment: Simple way: writing numpy images to disc as arrays via `np.save` and let the other script read it with `np.load`. But that is bound to cause trouble when they do not interlock properly. It would be better to import the functionalities of program 1 into program 2 (or vice versa) and let it run as one.

Comment: Yes, that is called IPC (Interprocess Communication): https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipc.html

Comment: Check also https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html